# validate score range and set different ranges of handicap for males and females c++

Tags: c++, validation

```
cout << " 13 - Golf Comeptition.\n";
        int score, handicap, netscore, players = 0, mswinner = 0, fswinner = 0, i = 1;
        string name, mwinner, fwinner;
        char gender;
        while (name != "end" || name != "END")
        {
            cout << "Is This Player Male Or Female (M/F).\n";
            cin >> gender;
            if (gender == 'M' || gender == 'm' || gender == 'F' || gender == 'f')
            {
                cout << "Enter player " << i << "s name.\n";
                cin >> name;
                cout << "Enter " << name << "s score.\n";
                cin >> score;
                if (score <= 60 || score >= 100)
                {
                    cout << "You Entered a score not in the range of 60-100.\n";
                    cout << "Enter " << name << "s score.\n";
                    cin >> score;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Enter " << name << "s handicap.\n";
                    cin >> handicap;

                    if (gender == 'M' || gender == 'm' && handicap <= 0 || handicap >= 28)cout << "please only enter a handicap within the range of 0-28 for males.\n and 0-36 for females.\n";
                    else if (gender == 'F' || gender == 'f' && handicap <= 0 || handicap >= 36) cout << "please only enter a handicap within the range of 0-28 for males.\n and 0-36 for females.\n";
                    else netscore = score - handicap;

                    if (gender == 'M' || gender == 'm')
                    {
                        if (netscore > mswinner)
                        {
                            mswinner = netscore;
                            mwinner = name;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (gender == 'F' || gender == 'f')
                    {
                        if (netscore > fswinner)
                        {
                            fswinner = netscore;
                            fwinner = name;
                        }
                    }
                    i++;

                }
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Please Enter A Valid Gender.\n";
            }
        }while(score <= 100 && score >= 60)
        cout << "The male winner is " << mwinner << " With a score of " << mswinner << ".\n";
        cout << "The female winner is " << fwinner << " With a score of " << fswinner << ".\n";
```

Most of this works like the validation of the gender if you enter anything but what is listed it wont work and will ask you to reenter.

There is one major flaw if you enter a score above 100 then it shows you the error message and allows you to reenter the score but then if you enter a score below 60 it jumps either back to or forward to enter the gender of the player.

I have done some research on validation and the most common way is the way I tried but I do not know why it does not work.

and because of this error I do not know if the validation for the handicap works judging from the experience with this part I do not think it does.

also I am new to this website and getting used to what people need from me so if I have missed anything you need please let me know if needed i can include pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works this way because that's what you coded it to do:

```
if (X)
{
    Y;
}
else
{
    Z;
}
```

If "X" is true, only the "Y" part gets executed, not both Y and Z. That's how an `if` statement works.

Here, the "X" part checks if the score is invalid. "Y" is your code that asks you to enter the score a second time. Just once. And "Z" is your code that asks the next question about the handicap.

So, if the originally entered score is invalid, your "Y" code asks for it again, and:

- it does not recheck the score value that was entered the second time around, to see if the second store is valid. If your intent is to require a valid score to be entered, this is not even the right way to do it. You have to keep asking to enter the right score until it's valid, not just ask it to be reentered only a second time, and not check it agin.
- And it doesn't execute the "Z" part. Because, as I mentioned, that's how the `if` statement works.

Comment: thanks for the answer I think i understand what i need to do